# How to write more shortly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I want to write more shortly. It might be written in one line. How can I do that?

```
    this.xxx = smt.filter(item => item.Id === this.smtStatus.ONE);
    this.yyy = smt.filter(item => item.Id === this.smtStatus.TWO);
    this.zzz = smt.filter(item => item.Id === this.smtStatus.THREE);
```

Which array methods should I use?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We need more context, does 'this' object contain those properties or are you creating them ? Try to be more precise and give us some context

Comment: This looks pretty short already. What else are you looking to shorten? Also, it can already be written in one line; Just separate them by semicolon

Comment: You can already write this in one line: https://jsfiddle.net/zgpfmy3v/

Comment: @jabaa: That's 3 lines :D

Comment: @Cerbrus I need something for `this` but the given code is in one line.

Comment: @nizarZizoune sorry about that. These are just variables.

Comment: @smac89 I just wanted to write more shortly because I did wonder. Maybe It could be done with another array function such as reduce, map something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you *could* shorten it using some destructuring, assuming `this` is the current scope:

```js
const [xxx, yyy, zzz] = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'].map(x => smt.filter(item => item.Id === this.smtStatus[x]));
```

That said, I wouldn't do this, as it's harder to read and maintain.

---

[Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16790884/steve)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69105911/1835379) also gave me another idea, you can use an getter function in your filter function to make your code more compact:

```js
function filterItemListById(list, getter) {
    return list.filter(item => item.Id === getter(this.smtStatus));
}

this.xxx = filterItemListById(smt, s => s.ONE);
this.yyy = filterItemListById(smt, s => s.TWO);
this.zzz = filterItemListById(smt, s => s.THREE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because something is short, doesn't mean it is good/better. Code that "reads" should be the priority both for yourself and your teammates.

If you just don't like the look of this, you could always toss the filtering into its own function. Might look like this:

```
filterItemListById(list, value) {
  if (list == null) return null;

  return list.filter(item => item.Id === value);
}

this.xxx = filterItemListById(smt, this.smtStatus.ONE); 
// etc...
```

Now, that is assuming you did NOT mean to combine *all three* lines into one. If that is what you meant, well...

Ok, so you can't assign to multiple variables (this.xxx, this.yyy, this.zzz) like that, usually. I know some people declare multiple variables in one line like:

```
var myInt1= 0, myInt2= 1, myInt3 = 2; // and so on
```

Declaring multiple primitives like this is fine, but I would never do this with any complicated logic, too messy looking.

To shorten, you have two options:

1. Put your logic into one or more functions with descriptive names, nothing wrong with this.
2. Put your variables into a list and loop over those variables while filtering. This is an awful approach, I like what you already have just fine, nothing wrong with it.

In short, don't worry about writing cute one-liners, you will only confuse yourself and your team later on. Focus on writing readable code so anyone can understand what is going on just by reading it line by line.

Comment: Cerbrus has a neat answer as usual, but wouldn't you have to reassign your const variables to the scoped variables?

Comment: You certainly would, yea.